# How to build a bullet proof cookie system?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I know the big posts about the cookie topic but I still have some unclear questions about the realization. My thoughts were these:

In my database I save for each of my user a `cookie_token` which is generated randomly when the account gets created. Just a random SHA1 or maybe a changed HASH of his BCRYPT.

Then my login logic would be:

If a user visits a private site

1. Is the Session `LoggedIn` true?

   1. Yes: All ok, stop further checks
   2. No: continue with 2.
2. Query the DB if the user with his ID has the same token as saved in his cookie.

   1. If Yes set the LoggedIn cookie
   2. Redirect.

But I've also read of a so called `series_identifier` but I couldn't figure out what this exactly is. As I understood it somehow should change every time the user creates a new session or something like this, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Can anyone give me a suggestion how to do that, or maybe an other approach to improve the security of the cookie / login process?

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: shooting cookies is wasteful

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: I would recommend regenerating the cookie_token for every login. You will need to keep track of all the valid cookie_tokens for each user. -- but that's better than having one static cookie hash.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe a static token and an on each login regenerating to be sure that no one highjaked or just forgot to log out on a public computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to build tamper-resistant cookies for long-term authentication, [this](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1) is a good introduction, and [this](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/02/split-tokens-token-based-authentication-protocols-without-side-channels) formalizes the strategy a bit further.

What you're doing is storing half the token as a selector (used in SELECT queries) and a hash of the other half of the token in the database.

To validate, you split the token in half, use the first to find the correct database record, then re-hash the second half and compare the one you just calculated with the one stored (using `hash_equals()`). If they match, great.

If you want to go a step further, you could also [encrypt your cookies using authenticated encryption](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/master/doc/Classes/Cookie.md), but that's probably overkill.